# Unable to run Windows net.exe in php system()

Tags: php

I have PHP v5.3.28 setup up in Internet Information Server on WIndows Server 2008.  I need to run a NET VIEW command from within my index.php file and display the output.  I have not found any way to make this happen.  I have been trying with system(), exec(), putting it into a .cmd file and executing that using code similar to that shown below.  Nothing comes out, nothing returned.  I can run other simple commands such as an xcopy, but using NET.exe does not seem to work at all.

```
echo "<pre>";
$str=system('C:\Windows\system32\NET1.exe VIEW \\tpptra01',$rtn); 
$str=system('D:\tmp\tpptra01\cpdbfiles.bat',$rtn);
$str=exec('C:\Windows\system32\NET1.exe VIEW \\tpptra01');
echo "</pre>";
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
echo "<pre>";
echo shell_exec("C:\Windows\system32\NET1.exe VIEW \\tpptra01");  
echo shell_exec("D:\tmp\tpptra01\cpdbfiles.bat");
echo shell_exec("C:\Windows\system32\NET1.exe VIEW \\tpptra01");
echo "</pre>";
```